# Coding in Visual Studio in Linux VM?

Tags: virtual-machine

Is it possible to set up a virtual machine so that I can run my development environment in Linux, but I get all the changes synced back to Windows? I can then use Visual Studio for editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a shared folder that is mounted in your VM. For example, create a folder in Windows, share it using the virtualization software you have and open it in Linux. All your changes immediately affect the "real" Windows folder.

---

To give you a more concrete example, in VirtualBox you go to the settings of your virtual machine, then to shared folders. Here, create a shared folder that maps to some folder on your Windows drive.

In the Linux VM you first have to install the [guest additions for Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). Then, use something like

```
mkdir -p /media/share
mount -t vboxsf <sharename> /media/share
```

where `<sharename>` is the name you've given the shared folder in the VirtualBox settings. Every change you make to this folder in Linux will automatically be visible in Windows and vice-versa.